# SwiftUI NavigationLink greyed out

Tags: foreach, swiftui, uisearchbar, swiftui-navigationlink

After implementing a search function for my application I want the search results to be clickable.
Therefore, I embedded the search result into a Navigation Link, but something is wrong with that.
When I try to search for an object, the search result gets greyed out and the Navigation Link is not clickable.

[image: greyed out NavigationLink]

Normally it looks like this (I know, that everyone knows that)
[image: Normal List view]

I implemented the search result in the the code snipped below under NavigationSearch()

To reproduce this error:
Use Mark van Wijnen's [NavigationSearch](https://gist.github.com/markvanwijnen/38c630e72735444a063594eaa5a582ed#file-navigationsearch-12-swift) out of his [Medium article](https://medium.com/@crystalminds/integrate-uisearchcontroller-in-ios-apps-using-swiftui-f3d31d04a93)

This class:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TracksView2: View {
    
    var tracks: [Track] = tracksData
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    var filtered : [Track] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return tracks
        } else {
            return tracks.filter({ $0.search(searchText) })
        }
    }
    
        var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationSearch(text: $searchText, searchResultsContent: {
                ForEach(filtered, id: \.id) { track in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TrackDetailView(tracks: track)) {
                        TrackRowView(track: track)
                    }
                }
            })
        } //: NAVIGATION
        
    }
}
```

(And replace TrackDetailView with an EmptyView)

Create a datamodel like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Track: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var headline: String
  var image: String
  var imagebig: String
  var gradientColors: [Color]
  var link: String
  var description: String
  var details: [String]
    
    func search(_ query: String) -> Bool {
        let searchable = [title, headline, description] + details

        return searchable.filter({ $0.contains(query) }).count > 0
    }
}
```

And use this sample data:

```
import SwiftUI

let tracksData: [Track] = [
  Track(
      title: "Spa-Francorchamps",
      headline: "Die Ardennenachterbahn ist für viele die faszinierenste Rennstrecke überhaupt. ",
      image: "road",
      imagebig: "preview",
      gradientColors: [Color("ColorBlueberryLight"), Color("ColorBlueberryDark")],
      link: "https://www.wikipedia.de/",
      description: """
                Bis
        """,
    details: ["7004m","8,50-18,50m", "21","100m"]
    ),
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is NavigationSearch?

Comment: NavigationSearch is just a name used to describe that the SearchBar is visible in the NavigationBar

Comment: it is needed reproducible example to debug.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/markvanwijnen/38c630e72735444a063594eaa5a582ed#file-navigationsearch-12-swift) you can find the NavigationSearch class

Comment: As a quick check I placed a NavigationLink in the overlay and it was disabled. Maybe the overlay isn't wired in to the NavigationView? Will you try and move the NavigationSearch out of the overlay? It can overwrite ForEach since the filtered collection has all items if search is empty.

Comment: @Helperbug I tried moving the NavigationSearch out of the overlay, but then it won't appear. I updated the code of the main class so that it is more compressed and without the unnecessary stuff. Maybe it is now easier to debug.

Comment: @Cobal NavigationSearch is a really cool component. It really doesn't wan't those results anywhere but in the overlay. I tried a few things and none were close. There is a learning opportunity here, so I will continue to tinker with the NavigationSearch view.

Comment: @Helperbug do you know an alternative way on how to implement a search function like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the UISearchBar wrapped in a UIViewRepresentable, credit to [Tim W Swift UI Contacts](https://tims.coding.blog/swift-stuff/building-a-fully-working-contact-list-in-swiftui). I have used it and it works. Maybe give it a try?

```
struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        
        @Binding var text: String
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none // --> here, we make some adjustments to the view so it better fits to our app
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
        
        return searchBar
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```